# Http link show problem in my laravel project

Tags: php, html, laravel, http, url

I found a great problem with my Laravel project.
I'm writing a link to my project like- **https://stackoverflow.com/**

[image]

However, when I'm running my project, this link doesn't completely spread to me.

[image]

It is cut off **http:** or **https:** from this link.

Comment: there is nothing in laravel that would be doing that by default. check any packages you have installed, particularly any middleware ... what does the html source of the rendered page show for that line?

Comment: Put a `dd();` right after the html link and have a look at the source code. What do you see? If you see https://... then you have implemented a post-render package or middleware. Packages similar to `purifier` can do that. But implementing this as a post-rendering feature doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found my problem in a third party packages.(renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed).